# How to use Secured WebSocket (WSS) in stand-alone Apollo application?

Tags: apollo-server

Apollo Server 2.0 ships with built-in server as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration-two-dot/#stand-alone). That means no Express integration is required when setting it up, so the implementation looks something like this:

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    announcement: String
  }
`;

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    announcement: () =>
      `Say hello to the new Apollo Server! A production ready GraphQL server with an incredible getting started experience.`
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

I'm implementing [subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/) to my app. How do I make the app use secured WebSocket protocol with subscriptions? Is it possible at all using the built-in server?

By default the server does not use WSS:

```js
server.listen({ port: PORT }).then(({ url, subscriptionsUrl }) => console.log(url, subscriptionsUrl));
```

spits out `http://localhost:4000/` and `ws://localhost:4000/graphql`.

In development I got my app to work fine but when I deployed to production I started getting these errors in console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS,
but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint
'ws://example.com/graphql'. This request has been blocked; this
endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

and

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure
WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Apparently configuring the WebSocket URL to start with `wss://` instead of `ws://` was enough.